# How to get 1 or 2 specific posts on top of my wordpress blog?

Tags: plugins, posts, sticky-post

Does anyone know how to get 1 or 2 specific posts on top of my wordpress blog all the time?
I mean just like in a forum where you can sticky a post so they are always on top of the other posts.

Is this maybe a simple line of code (i am not realy a coder) or does anyone knows a good plugin for this?

Any help would be realy appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it as a sticky post:

[image]

Comment: omg never seen this (blush).
Thanks.
is there also a way to give them a specific sticky order? Or just changes dates?

Comment: I think, at that point, you'd have to change their dates.